# Xamarin.Forms Проблема с Android.OS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

есть код.  Приложение для Android На Xamarin Forms

```
var root_path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            DisplayAlert("Directory", root_path, "OK");
```

Этот код рабочий. Работает в одном проекте.
C# VS2019

Создаем новое пустое тестовое приложение. Пишем 2 строчки
и мы не видим Android.OS
На подсветку предлагает внести using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
Но это не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пол дня бьюсь не могу понять почему не работает.

Рядом лежит проект в котором это работает. Любое новое пустое я не вижу значения
Android.OS......

Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. нужно в Assemblies добавить Mono.Android.dll
Почему он в одном проекте сам добавился а в другом не хочет все еще не понятно. Но проблема решилась.

Comment: Т.к. `Android.OS` специфична только для андроида, потому ссылка на эту библ. не добавляется в общий проект. Обычно в общий проект добавляют интерфейс, а в андройдный проект добавляют класс реализующий этот интерфейс и через DI получают экземпляр этого класса и вызывают нужный метод работающий с `Android.OS`. Пример такой реализации [здесь](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184761/can-i-call-method-from-mainactivity-by-using-a-caller-nested-in-mainpage-xaml).

Comment: @Bulson спасибо. разобрался. сделал как правильно.